# How can I cycle through recently used editors in VS Code without the intermediate Quick Open Recently Used menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pressing Ctrl+Tab in VS Code switches editors (by default?) to the most recently used editor. However, it does not immediately switch editors. It displays a drop-down menu listing all of the editors and with the desired editor being selected, so when you release Tab (key up) the editor is brought into view.

I would prefer to instantly switch editors the way Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn work, without a dropdown menu and with the editor in view on key down. Those shortcuts, however, do not switch editors in MRU order, but rather in the order they are displayed.

How can I switch editors in MRU order immediately without the drop-down menu?

Comment: it does not bring the editor into view for me when I keyup tab. I need to complete the operation by pressing enter...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try the following in your keybindings.json file (open with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
    // or openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor if you don't care about partitioning by group
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
    // or openNextRecentlyUsedEditor if you don't care about partitioning by group
},
```